# ¿Cómo realizo una consulta a un servicio SOAP con nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, soap

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/isbnservice.wso?WSDL';
var args = {};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //InsSujetoFotoFactura
            client.IsValidISBN13(args, function(err, result) {
                console.log("Resultado: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

He intentado realizar este ejemplo, para después llevarlo a mi web real, pero no sé qué argumentos pasarle...

Me devuelve error y no se saca datos. Alguien que me pueda poner un ejemplo, gracias

PD: El error que me lanza es el siguiente:

```
Resultado:{"statusCode":500,"body":"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.","headers":{"content-type":"text/html","server":"Microsoft-IIS/7.5","date":"Wed, 09 Aug 2017 16:08:45 GMT","connection":"close","content-length":"75"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"webservices.daehosting.com","port":80,"hostname":"webservices.daehosting.com","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/services/isbnservice.wso","path":"/services/isbnservice.wso","href":"http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/isbnservice.wso"},"method":"POST","headers":{"User-Agent":"node-soap/0.17.0","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"none","Accept-Charset":"utf-8","Connection":"close","Host":"webservices.daehosting.com","Content-Length":331,"Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8","SOAPAction":"\"\""}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso que estas haciendo es correcto a excepcion de que el body esta completamente vacio, y el servidor esta esperando un objeto con atributos que no estan.

Aplica el siguiente cambio en el test que haces 
Cambia

```
var args = {};
```

Por

```
var args = {"sISBN": ""};
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias! Había olvidado pasarle los argumentos correspondientes!